# Name of a heuristic for rule learning

Tags: terminology, heuristic

I have some rule learning code that evaluates a refinement to a rule with the following:

```
Value = NL*TP-FP*PL.
```

- NL is the number of negatives in the data set.
- PL is the number of positives in the data set.
- TP is number of positives covered by the
  refined rule.
- FP is the number of negatives covered by the refined
  rule.

What is the name for this heuristic/rule quality measure?

Chapter 7 in this book https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JsTXnjWexCEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA135#v=onepage&q=chapter%207&f=false gives a number of definitions for measures but I do not see this one. I want to know what it is called so I can look it up in the literature.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Not sure why it was down-voted but it does seem a bit sparse. Perhaps you could fill in some more background? We do also have a [tag:terminology] which perhaps you might add if that is your sole concern.